# SonataAdminbBundle access issue after logout

Tags: php, security, symfony, authentication, sonata-admin

I use SonataAdminBundle, but I have a some trouble. When I log as admin and then loging put, I still can acces to dashboard panel, and in profile displays like I am authenticated as admin. What I am doing wrong and how I can solve this issue ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure security.yml:

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN]
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
    SONATA:
        - ROLE_SONATA_PAGE_ADMIN_PAGE_EDIT  # if you are using acl then this line must be commented

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_manager

firewalls:
    # Disabling the security for the web debug toolbar, the profiler and Assetic.
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    # -> custom firewall for the admin area of the URL
    admin:
        pattern:            /admin(.*)
        context:            user
        form_login:
            provider:       fos_userbundle
            login_path:     /admin/login
            use_forward:    false
            check_path:     /admin/login_check
            failure_path:   null
            default_target_path:  /admin/dashboard
        logout:
            path:           /admin/logout
            target:         /admin/login
        anonymous:          true

    # -> end custom configuration

    # default login area for standard users

    # This firewall is used to handle the public login area
    # This part is handled by the FOS User Bundle
    main:
        pattern:             .*
        context:             user
        form_login:
            provider:       fos_userbundle
            login_path:     /login
            use_forward:    false
            check_path:     /login_check
            failure_path:   null
        logout:             true
        anonymous:          true

access_control:
    # URL of FOSUserBundle which need to be available to anonymous users
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

    # Admin login page needs to be access without credential
    - { path: ^/admin/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/logout$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/login_check$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

    # Secured part of the site
    # This config requires being logged for the whole site and having the admin role for the admin part.
    # Change these rules to adapt them to your needs
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN] }
    - { path: ^/.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Regards.